# Passing a parameter from a screen in SwitchNavigator to another in a TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have been having some problems passing parameters from a screen in a switchNavigator to another in a TabNavigator

```js
setvalue(response){
    this.setState({profile :response})
    
    console.warn(this.state.profile);
    this.state.navigate('Navigators',{profile: profile})
   
  }
```

The profile contains a JSON object of profile details. The navigation sends the date to the 'Navigators' screen which is just a TabNavigator

```js
const Navigators = createAppContainer(Userstack);

export default RootStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Login
    },
    Register: {
      screen: Registration
    },
   Navigators: {
      screen: Navigators
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }

);
```

How the TabNavigator is created.

```js
export default Userstack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    User: {
      screen: Profile
    },
    Discovery: {
      screen: DiscoveryNavigator
    },
  },
  {
      defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
          const { routeName } = navigation.state;
          let IconComponent = Ionicons;
          let iconName;
          if (routeName === 'User') {
            iconName = `md-contact`;
            
            IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge;
          } else if (routeName === 'Discovery') {
            iconName = `md-search`;
          }
          return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={27} color={tintColor} />;
        },
      }),
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#00FA9A',
        inactiveTintColor: 'black',
      },
    }

);
```

The screen I wish to access the profile information is

```js
export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.warn(props)
    this.State = {
      profile: this.props.navigation.params.profile
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `this.props.navigation.state.params`?

According to Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html,

*You can also directly access the params object with this.props.navigation.state.params. This may be null if no params were supplied, and so it's usually easier to just use getParam so you don't have to deal with that case.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes I tried the examples from the reference. I think the problem maybe with the data being passed to 'Navigator' instead of the 'profile' screen and that is causing the 'null'/undefined.

Comment: Yup, `this.state.navigate('Navigators',{profile: profile})` profile is undefined.
Cam you add `this.state.navigate('Navigators',{profile: 'profile'}); Just to see if you are getting `param` as a string or not.
If this working then replace that with `console.log(response);  //check in you getting the response
this.state.navigate('Navigators',{profile: response});`
This should fix the issue.

Comment: I have tried this before and the problem is even trying to pass a string comes up as undefined in my 3rd code block that is where 'Navigator' leads to and I am wondering if that is where the param is being passed to. Since there it decides to go to profile I dont think the param is being passed hence the undefined. I just dont know how to take the param I get in 'Navigator' and send it to the profile screen.